# Return the total records with mysqli::num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

why always $stmt->num_rows returns 0(zero), Whereas exist 2 records in **users** table. code:

```
    public function fetch_users()
    {
        if (!($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users"))){
            echo "prepare failed: (" . $this->mysql->errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        echo $stmt->num_rows;
    }
```

Comment: Check out Example 1: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: ok. with added "$stmt->store_result();" before "echo $stmt->num_rows;" solved.

Comment: @msoa You can (and should) post an answer to your own question below rather than note in the comments that you solved it.  Then when enough time has passed (2 days I think), mark your own answer as accepted with the tick mark.

Comment: I try do it, but say: "You can accept your own answer in 10 hours"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this change:

```
public function fetch_users()
{
    if (!($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users"))){
        echo "prepare failed: (" . $this->mysql->errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->store_result();

    echo $stmt->num_rows;
}
```